# JavaFX - How To Select A Specific Shape?

Tags: button, javafx, nodes, selection, shapes

Suppose I have the following two rectangles and I wanted to delete one:[image]

I know how to implement the delete button method, however I do not know how I can select between the shapes through a mouse-click. Could someone please give me some guidelines/examples as to how I would go about this. Thanks

Edit - Where I construct the rectangle:

```
if (treeview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == greenrect) {
                Rectangle rect = drag.createDraggableRectangle(200, 60, 200, 60);
                ObjectProperty<Point2D> mousePosition = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
                GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
                rect.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                container2.getChildren().addAll(rect);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the same event on both of the shapes like this:

```
private List<Shape> selectedShapes = new ArrayList<>();
@FXML
public void onShapeSelected(MouseEvent e) {
  Shape shape = (Shape) e.getSource();

  if (!selectedShapes.contains(shape)) {
    selectedShapes.add(shape);
  }
}

@FXML 
public void delete(ActionEvent e) {
   // delelte all the shapes from selected shapes list
}
```

What i did here is to save the selected nodes inside a list, and when the user will press delete you will be able to delete all the selected nodes.
I'm also recommend you to add selected style to the selected shape for notice the user that he selected the Shape and when the user re-press on the shape you can remove the shape from the list (don't forget to also remove the selected style)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.  What would the "!selectedShapes"  be??.. Thanks

Comment: array list of shapes for example

Comment: I see what your doing. That is great!   could you please tell me how I could use the method for my rectangle?. I have added the code where I initialise the green rectangle. The code shows how I add the rectangle to my pane from a treelist.  Thanks :D

Comment: greenRect.setOnMouseClicked(e -> onShapeSelected(e)); If you're using java 8

Comment: Fantastic! Worked a treat! :D

Comment: Just a quick question, how would I go about setting a style as you mentioned?.

Comment: Ignore that I figured it out. Thanks! :D